# Trouble with getting an instance of a room-Database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I unfortunately have big issues with getting an instance of a Room-Database for my android project. I followed the instructions on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html
But the last step won't work for me:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Their AppDatabase.java looks like this

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

My Problem: At "**AppDatabase db**" I get the error 'cannot resolve symbol "**AppDatabase**" '. This is quite senseful, because AppDatabase is just an abstract class. But how is this supposed to work in the tutorial?
I tried to get the instance in the onCreate method of my MainActivity. 
Here are my gradlefiles:
    buildscript {

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the second one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fabian.kohlmannkonstruktionen"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + 
rootProject.archRoomVersion
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:' + 
rootProject.archRoomVersion

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fabian.kohlmannkonstruktionen;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.migration.Migration;
import android.content.Context;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AppDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
}
...
```

AppDatabase.java

```
package com.example.fabian.kohlmannkonstruktionen;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.migration.Migration;
import android.content.Context;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AppDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Projekt.java

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

/**
 * Created by Fabian on 14.11.2017.
 */
@Entity
public class Projekt {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    Integer id;

    Integer projektnummer;
    Integer lohn,arbeitszeit;
    String projektname, firma;
    Boolean abgeschlossen;
    public Projekt(String projektname,String firma,Integer projektnummer){
        this.abgeschlossen=false;
        this.projektname=projektname;
        this.projektnummer=projektnummer;
        this.firma=firma;
    }
...getters and setters...
```

ProjektDao.java

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Fabian on 15.11.2017.
 */
@Dao
public interface ProjektDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Projekt")
    List<Projekt> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Projekt where id LIKE  :id")
    Projekt findByID(String id);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from Projekt")
    int countUsers();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Projekt... projekts);

    @Delete
    void delete(Projekt projekt);
}
```

Termin and TerminDao looks the same

This is the text from the gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [assemble]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\Fabian\AndroidStudioProjects\KohlmannKonstruktionen\app\src\main\java\TerminDao.java:14: warning: The query returns some columns [pausenzeit, startzeit, endzeit, lohnproh, mitarbeiter, standort] which are not use by Projekt. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. Projekt has some fields [projektnummer, lohn, arbeitszeit, projektname, firma, abgeschlossen] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: id, pausenzeit, startzeit, endzeit, lohnproh, mitarbeiter, standort. Fields in Projekt: id, projektnummer, lohn, arbeitszeit, projektname, firma, abgeschlossen.
    List<Projekt> getAll();
                  ^
C:\Users\Fabian\AndroidStudioProjects\KohlmannKonstruktionen\app\src\main\java\AppDatabase.java:13: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
                ^
C:\Users\Fabian\AndroidStudioProjects\KohlmannKonstruktionen\app\src\main\java\com\example\fabian\kohlmannkonstruktionen\MainActivity.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    ^
  symbol:   class AppDatabase
  location: class MainActivity
1 error
2 warnings

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

Comment: Just import your AppDatabase.java in Application class

Comment: Please add your activity code.

Comment: try to import AppDatabase

Comment: can you please post your Entity class and dao class here? i have tried with your current shared code which is work proper.

Comment: Sorry, i read this comments just now. First here is the whole project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnqlPFsLDSOSrUVYGXw37fyc15CL       and i edit my question with the important parts of the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `AppDatabase.class` is a little bit different to yours:

```
...
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "xxx")
                    // To simplify the codelab, allow queries on the main thread.
                    // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
...
```

And my `build.gradle` also includes `lifecycle`:

```
// for room
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0';
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0';
```

Comment: This does not work either :/ Just to get sure: Your AppDatabase.class is also abstract? I'm afraid that the mistake might be not in the Database, but a little stupid one.

Comment: Yes, the `AppDatabase.class` is abstract.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout my code that might help you.

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Product.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract ProductDao productDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInMemoryDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
```

Build.Gradle(Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Build.Gradle(App)

```
// Room
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
```

This will create only one instance. this works well in my code.

Comment: This looks good, but it still says $"Cannot resolve symbol 'AppDatabase"$ Could you show me your gradle file? Maybe i messed something up there.  And you never implement the abstract class AppDatabase at all?

Comment: can you please add your log here?

Comment: What is **destroyInstance()** for?

Comment: it is just to destroy instance of database

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a case of copy/pasting.

Re-type @PrimaryKey etc so Android Studio knows you're using them, or the IDE just treats it as text